# Networking.service fails with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, networking, 22.04, systemd, network-bridge

Under Ubuntu 22.04 my networking.service is failing. Apparently because `ifup@br0.service` is failing. But all networks are up. I use `/etc/network/interfaces` to set up the networks. When I try to bring up the `ifup@br0.service` I get: `RTNETLINK answers: File exists`. The fix for this, was to add "`pre-up /bin/ip addr flush dev br0`" to `/etc/network/interfaces`. But after booting, there is no `br0` anymore. `sudo ifup br0` gives: `no such interface`. Removing the `pre-up` and rebooting restores `br0` but now networking.service and `ifup@br0.service` are failing again. Catch22...

This is the relevant part of the interfaces config:

```
allow-hotplug eth0 eth1 eth1.300 eth1.254

iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp on
        bridge_maxwait 5
        address 192.168.###.###/24
        pre-up /bin/ip addr flush dev br0
        post-up /bin/ip route add 172.x.x.x/23 via 192.168.x.x
        down /bin/ip addr flush dev br0
        down /bin/ip route del 172.x.x.x/23 via 192.168.x.x

iface br0 inet6 static
        pre-up /usr/sbin/modprobe ipv6
        address fc00:######
        netmask 64
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You seem to be on the dangerous path to a Well-known Error: Applying a "solution" before diagnosing the problem.  Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.

Comment: Ubuntu uses `netplan`, rather than simply editing `/etc/network/interfaces`. Please see `https://netplan.io` and `https://netplan.io/examples`.

Comment: I disagree. E.g. this is the method Canonical states, to set up a bridge for kvm: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KvmWithBridge